# Can I mix "would" and "kind of"?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct?

> The test would be kind of homework activity like last time.

Comment: No. The correct version depends on what you mean to say; it's unfair to ask us to guess before composing an answer.

Comment: Sorry for being unfair :D My classmate wrote a letter to our english teacher and I felt something bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'kind of' could be replaced by 'sort of' or 'type of' to sound more correct.

Also, you should have an 'a' in there - i.e. 'the test would be a type of homework activity'.

However, this still sounds dumb.

You should just say 'the test would/will be a homework activity' if it would/could/will be.

I'm supposing there is not a case where it wont be a homework activity, is there?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not correct, not only as it lacks 'a' but using 'a kind' would mean the test would be  a homework activity(which never happens). I think you mean-:"the test would be based on homework activity like last time".

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the sentence

- *The test would be kind of homework activity like last time.*

**provided**:

1. the speaker is hypothesizing about a future test.
2. the speaker intends to be understood as believing
   that the test would (hypothetically) consist
   of the same kinds of problems as appear on homework.
3. with *like last time*, the speaker is referring **either**

   - to the last homework set,
     **or**
   - to the last test.

*Kind of*, in *kind of homework activity*, is an idiomatic hedge that means "like, similar to". I think most English speakers, even learners, kind of understand this usage already. Semantically, it's second-order predicate calculus, but who cares?

Comment: You would still need an indefinite article before **kind**.

Comment: Yes, if you meant _a variety of_; but _kind of_ is a frozen idiom that mightaswell not have a space in it. In eye dialect, it doesn't; the usual eye dialect spelling is "kinda". And it's a hedge, not a quantifier.

Comment: Do you think we can use in this way? He referred to the last test which was done at home.

Comment: English speakers can and do use it this way all the time. Otherwise there wouldn't be a common eye dialect spelling. He may be constrained by his teacher to be learning nonsense rules, which is sad, but that's his problem.